# Restart Systemd service automatically whenever a directory changes (any file inside it)

Tags: unix, systemd

How do I restart a Systemd service when a file change. I've got a Java service that I want to reload when any jar file changes.

This is my setup:

**srv.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=srv 0.1: Service's description
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/srv
ExecStart=/opt/srv/bin/srv
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**srv.path**

```
[Path]
PathModified=/opt/srv/lib/
```

I also tried using `PathChanged` and using a file instead a directory.

When I installed the service I executed: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and  `sudo systemctl enable srv`

Thanks!

Comment: Not tested so not an answer, but from the documentation it seems that `path` units are only useful for activating (starting) other units. Here you could probably create `srv-restart.path` with `PathChanged=/opt/srv/lib/` and `srv-restart.service` with `ExecStart=systemctl restart srv.service`.

Comment: It seems that if you name it the same as the service (with .path) the path file refers to the same service: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html however... I don't know if it only starts a service or it even restart it if it is already running

Comment: As I understand it from the docs, `srv.path` can only do the equivalent of `systemclt start srv.service`, so for automating restarts you will need another service, which when started restarts your service.

Comment: You need to start it `systemctl start srv.path` - and to have it started on boot `systemctl preset srv.path`

Comment: see (second) answer by JdeBP http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203637/how-can-i-start-a-file-processing-daemon

Comment: Thanks for your comments, last two replies make my service start if a file change... But once it is started, if a file is modified, the service is not reloaded again. Do you know if this is feasible?

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4324

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Michal Politowski's comment is exactly correct.  I use this method to automatically restart services when new artifacts are deployed.  It is very helpful.

To be clear, you need:

**srv.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=srv 0.1: Service's description
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/srv
ExecStart=/opt/srv/bin/srv
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**srv-watcher.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=srv restarter
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl restart srv.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**srv-watcher.path**

```
[Path]
PathModified=/opt/srv/lib

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Are there any guarantees about when this is triggered if lots of files are getting changed in rapid succession?

Comment: Is important to remember that the «.path» unit also needs to be enabled. In this case:
`systemctl enable srv-watcher.path && systemctl start srv-watcher.path`

Comment: If your restart service is not of the same name as the  `.path`  file then just add `Unit=nameofmyrestart.service` to the `[Path]` section of your `.path` file.   https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html#Unit=

Comment: Works fine in CentOS for restarting Kestrel (ASP.NET Core)

Comment: the .service need to be disabled otherwise it will run on boot... also note that this does not work with sub-folders

Comment: What if you want to run the service after a succession of file changes? i.e. only run it once the consecutive changes stop so we avoid restarting for each change.

Answer (score 18):

The answer above is almost great, but it's missing a few things that took me a while to figure out. Others came across the same issues, see the comments section.

```
systemctl enable srv-watcher.{path,service}
systemctl start srv-watcher.{path,service}
```

srv.service

```
[Unit]
Description=srv 0.1: Service's description
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/srv
ExecStart=/opt/srv/bin/srv
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

srv-watcher.service

```
[Unit]
Description=srv restarter
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=10
StartLimitBurst=5

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl restart srv.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

srv-watcher.path

```
[Path]
Unit=srv-watcher.service
PathChanged=/opt/srv/lib 
# trigger on changes to a file not just create/delete
# don't put comments in the same line as the command

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If it is working, you will see these messages in journalctl

```
$: journalctl -f -o cat -u srv-watcher
Starting srv-watcher...                                                                                          
Started srv-watcher.
```

Other things to note, patch may fire many times but the srv-watcher.service will respect the default limit of 5 restarts in 10 second intervals. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#StartLimitIntervalSec=interval

Comment: Thanks for your answer-- it really makes sense of the accepted answer. Question: have you looked at putting in explicit "Requires=" or "After=" for the watcher service files? Does it matter and would it work like one would expect?

Comment: What if you want to run the service after a succession of file changes? i.e. only run it once the consecutive changes stop so we avoid restarting for each change.

Comment: Getting `Failed to restart srv.service: Interactive authentication required.` This is because I have strict access controls on the system & running systemctl might need sudo. `kill` would need process id for the srv.service but would need some minor scripting to obtain the pid